# Join two models together using a common column

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `unique_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `bible_photo` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `file_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `unique_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And two corresponding models

**Models**

```
class TProfiles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profiles'

class Photo( models.Model ):
    file = models.FileField( upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def extension(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        return extension
```

I want to access all profiles and their corresponding profile picture, based on the unique ID they both share. I have the following in my views.py file. However, although I can access them both individually, I cannot combine them to pass to the template.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all
    profiles = TProfiles.objects.all

    return render_to_response("register.html", {
        "form": form, "photos": photos,
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

**Update**

I tried adding `profile = models.ForeignKey(TProfiles)` to my Photo model, but I keep getting complaints about missing columns relating to the Profiles table. Surely I don't have to duplicate them in to Photos table?

```
OperationalError at /register/
(1054, "Unknown column 'bible_photo.profile_id' in 'field list'")
```

And this is the line of code in my template that it is moaning about. I am trying to see if I can access the profile from the photo.

```
{% for p in photos %}
    <h1>{{ p.profile }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why you dont use [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)?

Comment: I was just wondering about that. I have added "profile = models.ForeignKey(TProfiles)" to the Photo model. Do you know how I would implement this in the view?

Comment: The foreign key has now been added but I seem to get an error with my columns - please see my Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `models.py` like this:

```
class TProfiles(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profiles'

class Photo( models.Model ):
    file = models.FileField( upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    event_location_time = models.ForeignKey(TProfiles)      

    def extension(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        return extension
```

And change your `view` like this:

```
def register(request):
    profiles = TProfiles.objects.all()

    return render_to_response("register.html", {
        "form": form, "profiles": profiles,
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

And in your `template` you can use :

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    #access to profile object
    {% for photo in profile.photo_set.all %}
     #access to each profile photo object
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really good! I am having a little trouble unfortunately. I now get the error "unknown column 'profile_id'". Is that because of the newly added PK?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it does anything. I was wondering if I could just add a foreign key manually to the profiles table? Do you know what the SQL would look like for that?

Comment: I have it working now, after fiddling with the database to get PK's working. Thanks for your patience.